# Why would my Hoya ND8 Pro 1 decrease the white balance dramatically?

Tags: filters, troubleshooting, white-balance

I've just bought the Hoya ND8 Pro filter (+3 stops). After some tests, i've just notice that the results are very different from a single shot. After some tests, here is my conclusions :

1. The ND filter under expose at -0.70 pts
2. The White Balance is totally messed up, down of -1500 k (ND filter pictures are a lot bluish)

Does this behavior result of the Hoya, or is it the same from all ND Filters ? 
Thanks !

Comment: That sounds **very** wrong; more like the results of an 80N9 filter then an 0.9-density ND filter. You would notice a distict blue filter colour just looking at it if the filter itself is causing a WB shift that large. What kind of "tests" were you performing?

Comment: Two kinds : shooting a water fall, and some object on my living room table. I was wrong on the WB, the delta is 350k.
Anyway, i'm thinking trading the ND8 for a ND400.

Comment: Neither of those (both are scenes rather than test targets) can tell you anything useful about the filter's actual density or colour; your camera may be making different decisions about the scene based on the light level. You'd need to shoot something like a grey card using manual exposure and white balance to get a real reading of the filter's characteristics.

Comment: I just did tests on my grey card, the test is result is near Itai answers below : the grey goes into the blue.

Comment: Those numbers, though, are more like a Wratten 82-series filter, the sort that you'd use to slightly cool sunset lighting or shoot tungsten film with household incandescents, which is a far cry from what your question originally described. There's "colour shift" (81- and 82-filter equivalents), and then there's "colour conversion"; you were talking about full-cut CTB/Wratten 80-series conversion originally.

Answer (score 9):

This question made me curious, so I tried an experiment using one HD polarizer and 3 ND filters (HMC ND8, Pro 1D ND16 and HMC N4D00) and a white-balance and color-chart.

My first observation is that the camera produces highly varied results when left to its own, particularly with exposure.

Using Multi-Segment metering:

- The HD polarizer gives a +1 EV delta which is perfect.
- The ND8 gave a +2 EV delta which is one stop short.
- The ND16 also gave a +2 EV delta which is two stop short.
- The ND400 also gave a +2 EV delta which is way too short, which suggest I reached the metering limit of the camera.

Under the same conditions with Spot metering:

- The HD polarizer gives a +1 EV delta which is perfect.
- The ND8 gave a +2.5 EV delta which is half a stop short.
- The ND16 gave a +2.5 EV delta which is 1.5 stops short.
- The ND400 gave a +3.5 EV delta which is way too short again. This shows the limit of spot metering to be lower than multi-segment.

Manually setting the exposures to the correct amount according to the strength of the ND filter gives perfectly consistent results in terms of exposure but shows variations in white-balance.

Given a filterless exposure of F/4 1s ISO 200:

- The HD polarizer needed 2s and had virtually no effect on white-balance. *I knew this actually since it was the reason I sold my B+W filters which gave terrible color-shifts and replaced them with Hoya HD Polarizers*.
- The ND8 needed 8s for the same exposure. White-balance however became noticeably more green. The grey patch on the color chart with RGB values (199, 199, 199) unfiltered became (189, 202, 179).
- The ND16 needed 16s for the same exposure and had absolutely 0 effect on white-balance, keeping the grey patches all perfectly neutral.
- The ND400 was exposed for 401s which gave the same brightness but gave results a slight bluish tint. The RGB (199, 199, 199) patch became (199, 213, 216), so actually less red.

In observation is seems the **ND filters are well calibrated in terms of exposure but the camera struggles with lower light levels.** Other than the ND16 Pro 1D (and HD Polarizer), these ND filters seem to have an effect on color. Having no multiple copies of the same one, I cannot say if this is a sample variation or simply properties of the filter.

The only thing to do **to get WB perfect is to shoot RAW** since the reduced light-levels do not allow a Custom WB reading to be made with the filters on under moderate light conditions at least.

Comment: Great tests ! I'm near you, for the ND8, my greys are not greys anymore !

Comment: Yeah. Looks like I'll be retiring the ND8 :) They do not seem to make a Pro 1D ND400, I'd buy that consider the great results from the other high-end filters.

Comment: It's a shame, because i was going for the ND400 ! Now i'm lost !

Comment: Well, the ND400 is not that bad! Visible change yes but not as dramatic as the ND8. Plus, its easy to correct once you know.

Answer (score 0):

Does the filter look neutral to the eye?

My guess is that your camera is getting confused by it.

Try shooting in manual (WB, Aperture, shutter), set everything up for a normal shot, take one, then use the filter, and compare results.

Comment: My shots are made in manual settings :)